# Is there a way to dynamically set the height of a map pop up?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I have a custom map pop up that opens when I click on an icon, but if you click the icon when it is too high on the map, the top of the pop up is cut off.

I've attempted to edit the height with css via `.mapboxgl-popup-content`. However, the height of the pop up varies depending on the information in the pop up.

If I set the height to be roughly the max height that the pop up could be (in pixels), then the pop up shows up correctly, and none of it is cut off. However, the shorter variants of the pop up are too high above the map icon that was clicked.

Is there a way to dynamically set the pop up height so that it displays on the map correctly?

Comment: Did you try to use max-height https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height ?

Comment: I did try max-height, but with no luck.